# How to understand the definition of "manifestly constant-evaluated"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

[P0595](https://wg21.link/P0595) introduced the `std::is_constant_evaluated()` function. The paper discusses how there are some situations where the containing expression is a constant expression, but one that the compiler is not required to evaluate at compile time. The example given is:

```
constexpr double power(double b, int x) {
  if (std::is_constant_evaluated() && x >= 0) {
    // ...
    // return r;
  } else {
    // Let the code generator figure it out.
    return std::pow(b, (double)x);
  }
}

double thousand() {
  return power(10.0, 3);
}
```

The compiler may evaluate `power(10.0, 3)` at compile time, but is not required to. Therefore, `is_constant_evaluated` returns false.

The paper therefore introduces a concept of "manifestly constant-evaluated":

> Our approach is to precisely identify a set of expressions that are "manifestly constant-evaluated" (a new technical phrase) and specify that our new function returns `true` during the evaluation of such expressions and `false` otherwise.
>
> Specifically, we include two kinds of expressions in our set of expressions "manifestly constant-evaluated". The first kind is straightforward: Expressions in contexts where the standard already requires a constant result, such as the dimension of an array or the initializer of a constexpr variable. ...

This makes sense to me. However, the actual wording in the standard confuses me:

> An expression or conversion `e` is *manifestly constant-evaluated* if it is:
>
> - a *constant-expression*, or ...

In other words, the standard specifies that all constant expressions are manifestly constant-evaluated, which (to me) does not seem to incorporate the requirement that the expression appears in a context where a constant expression is required. The proposal remarks that `power(10.0, 3)` is a core constant expression, which is also my understanding; this makes it a constant expression. If all constant expressions are manifestly constant-evaluated, then it seems that `is_constant_evaluated` must return true here.

How should I understand the definition in the standard so that it has a precise meaning that is consistent with the intent of the proposal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is my favorite. It doesn't say " a constant expression." It says "a *constant-expression*."<sup>†</sup>

*constant-expression* is a grammar term. It's a stand-in for those places in C++ grammar where a constant expression is mandated.

For instance, the grammar (specifically, the grammar) for a [*template-argument*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument) is *constant-expression* (or a *type-id* or an *id-expression*), so this rule means that when evaluating a *constant-expression* that appears as a *template-argument*, that evaluation is manifestly constant-evaluated.

In contrast, the grammar in `if constexpr` does *not* take a *constant-expression*, it just [takes a *condition*](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.select.general#nt:selection-statement). So this bullet isn't enough to cover `if constexpr`, which is why there is a special extra bullet to cover "the condition of a constexpr if statement."

---

<sup>†</sup> Imagine having to answer this question verbally. You can hear the hyphen, right?

Comment: Not just the hypen, the italics too. Are we reaching a point where C++ cannot be described aloud? Mere human vocal speech patterns no longer suffice?

Comment: Don't forget the sans-serif font.