# Constexpr prvalue lifetime, is MSVC too strict?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, visual-studio-2022

Consider a `std::array<T, N>` derived class with the following constexpr additions:

```
static constexpr auto size() { return N; }
constexpr const_reference operator[](size_t Index) const
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    {
        static_assert(Index < size(), "Subscript out of range.");
        return data()[Index];
    }
    else
        return std::array<T, N>::operator[](Index);
}

// Outside of class.
constexpr myArray<uint8_t, 42> Array = {};
static_assert(Array[0] == 0, "Never called");
```

MSVC throws an error on the first `static_assert` because accessing `Index` is considered `a read of a variable outside its lifetime`. Given the nature of the prvalues, I can't figure out why there'd be any lifetime issues for `Array[0]`. Thoughts?

Comment: `Index` is just a regular old runtime value, I don't understand why you expect to be able to use it in a `static_assert`... (Or maybe you're grossly overestimating the effects of `constexpr`.)

Comment: The simple `return data()[Index];` also uses it and there's no complaints there, and the returned value is used in the last `static_assert` properly. So could you elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are 'constexpr' parameters not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591970/why-are-constexpr-parameters-not-allowed)

Comment: The problem here is that is a terrible error message. The issue is simply that `Index` isn't a constant expression and needs to be for `static_assert` (because function parameters aren't constexpr).

Comment: [Related reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65429926/2069064): `static_assert` takes a _`constant-expression`_, not a constant expression.