# Manifestly constant-evaluated expressions: inconsistency between constexpr and consteval?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, consteval

I'm comparing the behavior of `constexpr` and `consteval`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

[[nodiscard]] constexpr std::string_view DispCExpr(int) noexcept {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        return "consteval\n";
    } else {
        return "not consteval\n";
    }
}

[[nodiscard]] consteval std::string_view DispCEval(int) noexcept {
    // in consteval function std::is_const_evaluated() is always true
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        return "consteval\n";
    } else {
        return "not consteval\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**) {
    constexpr std::string_view sv1 = DispCExpr(2);
    std::cout << sv1;  // constant evaluated
    std::string_view sv2 = DispCExpr(2);
    std::cout << sv2;  // not constant evaluated!
    std::string_view sv3 = DispCEval(2);
    std::cout << sv3;  // constant evaluated!
    // KO: normal argc not known at compile time
    // std::string_view sv4 = DispCEval(argc);
    // std::cout << sv4;  // constant evaluated
}
```

Calling the `constexpr` function `DispCExpr` in order to initialize a `constexpr` variable actually makes it *constant evaluated* (`std::is_constant_evaluated` returns `true`).
But calling it, with a compile-time known constant in order to initialize a non-`constexpr` variable seems not to be a *manifestly constant-evaluated expressions*.
On the other hand, the `consteval` function `DispCEval` is always *constant evaluated* (as the compiler is warning me about [live](https://godbolt.org/z/zhG6obxY6)).

Why is there, what seem an inconsistency to me, between the `sv2` and the `sv3` situation?

[How to understand the definition of "manifestly constant-evaluated"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429853/how-to-understand-the-definition-of-manifestly-constant-evaluated) seems to address the issue of a function call with constant but I'm failing to understand the difference between *manifestly constant-evaluated expressions*  and such a call.

Comment: The "inconsistency" is exactly why `consteval` functions were added to the language. There was a desire for a mechanism that makes functions *always* constant evaluated, regardless of where they are used.

Comment: Because having a constexpr function doesn't mean it must be called at compile time. It can be called at runtime like ordinary function.

Comment: [consteval: a function which is "required" to execute only at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742167/12002570). That is not true for `constexpr` function.

Comment: I understand the difference between `consteval`, `if consteval` (C++23) and `constepxr` what I can't grasp is why `DispCExpr(2)` is not considered as a *manifestly...* and so on.

Comment: The question was closed, though I don't see how the linked supposedly duplicate explain why a call on constant does not qualified for `std::is_constant_evaluated`. It is about the difference between `consteval` and `constexpr` in terms of compile-time requirements which is not my question here... May I have an hint on how to rephrase if it is not clear enough?

Comment: @user12002570 I think we need a different duplicate.

Comment: There's not much to say here, other than `std::is_constant_evaluated()` having a dumb design. It returns true only if something *forces* the function to run at compile-time (such as being `consteval` or its result being used at compile-time). It's saner version is GCC's non-standard `__builtin_constant_p(...)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wouldn't call `__builtin_constant_p` [saner](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112296). It's certainly...different.